# Java IDN Conversion of the german Eszett "ß"

Tags: java, idn

I encounter an issue with converting domain names which contains the german Eszett "ß", usually I use the java IDN class to do it, but it does not work as expected on this specific case.

```
        String domainName = "faß.de";
        String expectedAsciiDomainName = "xn--fa-hia.de";
        if (expectedAsciiDomainName.equals(IDN.toASCII(domainName))) {
            System.out.println("Cool");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not cool");
        }
```

Any ideas of why it does not work ? thanks

I've seen that in PHP there is an option for nontransitional processing of IDN conversion which works perfectly :

```
echo idn_to_ascii('faß.de', IDNA_NONTRANSITIONAL_TO_ASCII) . PHP_EOL; // return xn--fa-hia.de
```

is there a way to do the same thing on java ?

Comment: On my computer, using JDK 15, `IDN.toASCII("faß.de")` returns `fass.de`.

Comment: indeed, on my computer too, but it should not... you can see for example at Verisign the right conversion for this domain : [here](https://www.verisign.com/en_US/channel-resources/domain-registry-products/idn/idn-conversion-tool/index.xhtml)

Comment: From the docs: *ToASCII and ToUnicode. These 2 operations employ Nameprep algorithm, which is a profile of Stringprep, and **Punycode** algorithm to convert domain name string back and forth.* Verify it on https://www.punycoder.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found this library : https://github.com/unicode-org/icu
(as java class IDN.toASCII use IDNA2003 instead of IDNA2008) which works perfectly...